# Automate iOS build installation on devices

Tags: ios, install

We have a large number of iOS applications which we would like to install on several devices. Is there a way to install the ipa files from a dropbox location?

Answer (score 2):

Create a plist like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>items</key>
  <array>
    <dict>
      <key>assets</key>
      <array>
        <dict>
          <key>kind</key>
          <string>software-package</string>
          <key>url</key>
          <string>https://example.com/path/to/file.ipa</string>
        </dict>
      </array>
      <key>metadata</key>
      <dict>
        <key>bundle-identifier</key>
        <string>com.mybundle</string>
        <key>bundle-version</key>
        <string>1.0.0</string>
        <key>kind</key>
        <string>software</string>
        <key>subtitle</key>
        <string>My App</string>
        <key>title</key>
        <string>My App</string>
      </dict>
    </dict>
  </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Make a link to open this plist with itms-services, then click the link on an iOS device:

```
itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://example.com/path/to/manifest.plist
```

Comment: Is there a way to push the build and have it installed directly on few test devices. I don't want a user to click this link from an iOS device, then it becomes a manual action.

Comment: @Rpj You can push with USB, but is that suitable before I write an answer?

Comment: Kindly provide your views on USB as well.

Comment: @Rpj Apologies, forgot about this question :) I've added an answer

Answer (score 2):

If you can connect the devices over USB, you can use [**Apple Configurator**](https://itunes.apple.com/app/apple-configurator/id434433123). This lets you install apps on batches of devices automatically.

Add the devices to Apple Configurator's supervision and import the apps, then press Prepare and connect the devices sequentially (or all at once if you have enough USBs). The apps will be automatically installed on all subsequently connected devices.

[image]

To fully comply with the requirements in the question, you can import IPAs from Dropbox ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout this site:

http://fir.im

just upload your .ipa file and all device can install your app from a simple url.

Comment: It's chinese or something like it, you cannot read this site as English language?

Comment: @Rob I think it's very easy to use because you just need 3 steps. Maybe you can use Chrome to translate the words. :]